# kprintf printing out block letters

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

In my C program in an operating systems code (on the kernal side), I am trying to use `kprintf` to print a character, but when even I do, it prints it as well as some block character which has these four small circles in it.

```
kprintf(&ch);
```

Does anyone know whats going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `printf()` family of functions take a *format string* which tells what you want to print.  You cannot print a character directly as you are doing, because `printf()` (or `kprintf()` as the case may be) will continue to read as if it were a string.  You want something like:

```
kprintf("%c", ch);
```

The format string tells `printf()` what additional arguments to expect. In this case, `%c` indicates a character argument.